# Decagon Container in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to react native. Guys how can we make a decagon container in react native. I have followed a few tutorials but wasn't able to achieve a decagon container.It will be great help Guys.

Comment: Hi, you mean container design has like decagon ?

Comment: @Elango  Hi.I mean a container that is shaped like a decagon, like normally we have circular or square containers. I want a container that is decagonal in shape. Thank you!